# Why the induced noise is sometimes additive but sometimes works as a constant?

Tags: audio, adc, noise, emi-filtering, hum

Why sometimes the noise (e.g., induced 50hz hum) is added to a useful signal (thus increasing its 50hz value), but sometimes it works as a noise floor - has a static value and can be overpowered by a useful signal?

Let's say I have a cassette tape head which picks up 50hz hum 10db above its noise floor.

However if I reproduce a flat frequency response tape using that head, I will get a flat curve with only 1db bump at 50hz.

Question is: why is that so? Why the bump is not 10db above the response curve?

Comment: You might be able to hold a conversation with someone across a room but, if there were thirty other people trying to have conversations, you'd be scuppered.

Comment: But if three of us say the same word, it should sound 3 times louder...

Comment: Not quite. Each voice will have such massive signal frequency and phase differences to each other voice that the total RMS level won't be three times higher.

Comment: @MatildaBentefor I think you will find that you want to look into how you estimate your spectrum. Specifically, I think your PSD estimate isn't what you think it is. Question: When you do that "flat curve with a bump at 50 Hz", what is your resolution bandwidth if you're doing that with a spectrum analyzer, or what is your frequency resolution if you're doing it digitally?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No sir, it's not about that. I've been digitizing various legacy audio mediums for last 20 years. I live where devices work of 50hz. So there is plenty of 50hz+harmonics in the air. And I always see them in every device. However in some cases those 50hz are ADDED to the signal, thus requiring me to make some post-EQ. While in other cases they are OVERPOWERED by the signal. And I am wondering, what's the difference? Why these "hums" don't work in a similar way? It's as if there were 2 different versions of "hum". What's the physics behing this?

Comment: they're always going to be additive, foremost (if they are strong enough to drive your system into saturation, so that they become partially multiplicative, you would have other problems). Sometimes they are above or below signal (and signal-inherent noise floor). Is that what you mean with "OVERPOWERED"? Maybe a picture might help!